# Resource Editor for Windows Applications to replace Icon , open source, quick and simple

Tags: windows, icons, open-source, resources

I am using Windows XP, Windows 2003 and Windows 2000.

Each application has a primary icon that is displayed in the taskbar and on the desktop and in the application window. The icon lives in the application files.

Can you name a simple and preferably open source resource editor that allows me to quickly and simply replace the icon. Would be great if it is a "one click solution" that does the necessary steps transparent in the background, so not much internal knowledge of windows specifics internals is necessary and icons can be replaced quickly.

If it is part of a bigger software development tool (like compilers) it should be possible to extract just the resource editor and deploy only that to the machines where I work without installation hassle.

[There is "Resource Hacker"](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/rh_history.html) which seems to do the job but is no longer maintained

There is "eXeScope" hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA003525/eimgexe.htm which is not open source and not free and also not maintained

**EDIT**: Thank you  Superuser friends who edit the links, but I have to revert it on each edit. This is a limitation of the superuser interface for "new users". Superuser, do some homework.

Comment: By open source do you really mean open source, or do you mean "free so I don't have to pay anything"?

Comment: I edited the links for you :-)

Comment: Open source has great advantages which I honour, but free software with closed source that does not expire would also solve the issue.

Comment: IVo, thank you. I found out it is pointless, I have to revert it on each edit. Such is life ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource Hacker is a good resource editor.

You might be interested also in [**ResEdit**](http://www.resedit.net/). It's free and updated regularly.

> **What is ResEdit?**
>
> ResEdit is a free Resource Editor for
>   Win32 programs. You can use it if you
>   want to use dialogs, icon, version
>   information or other types of
>   resources. Output files can be
>   compiled by any Win32 compiler, like
>   MinGW and Microsoft Visual C++. To
>   open a file which uses Win32 API
>   symbolic constants, you will also need
>   Win32 header files (usually coming
>   with you compiler).

Comment: Thank you, looks like a great project. Nevertheless it seems to me it is not exactly what I am looking for. I have to compile (or at least use a linker) afterwards? So I need original sourcefiles?

Comment: No. Open the EXE file with ResEdit, edit the resource you want (icons, text strings, bitmaps, ...), save and that's it! I just tried and it worked fine. 

The rest is just extra features!

Answer (score 2):

I still use Resource Hacker, I think it is the best bet and even though it is not maintained, it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/index.html).  (See [this tutorial](http://icofx.ro/tutorials/tutorial5.html)).  I found it to be much easier to work with than Resource Hacker.