# Changing an EXEs product name in Vista

Tags: windows-vista

When I right click an executable I installed in Windows Vista and open the properties, it contains a product name and file description in the details tab (in my case, the exe's file name is "chrome.exe" but the product name is "Google Chrome"). Is there any place where I could change this name? Thanks!

(Please note I have a German OS so I'm not perfectly sure it's called "product name" in English.)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those properties are given when the executable is compiled, so they are hardcoded. You might be able to change them with a [resource editor](https://superuser.com/questions/48395/resource-editor-for-windows-applications-to-replace-icon-open-source-quick-and), although I can't really help you on that one.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the summary information of an PRODUCT_NAME.msi (most windows software use msi installer for installation) using Installshield Direct Editor or using Orca which is shipped with Windows Installer 4.5 (now 5)SDK.

You will need to install the SDK, then go to its install directory & install Orca. 
Then you will need to open the *.msi file in Orca click "View" -> "Summary Information". Then do the changes to th einfo, save the install package & close Orca.
If you now view the summary info, it will refect your changes.